# Including machine round-off in ode error bound

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to estimate the smallest step length that can be used in an ODE method without the machine round-off error dominating. Intuitively, I would expect this $h$ to be roughly such that when doing $N$ steps and dragging along an error of $\epsilon$ in each step, $N\epsilon$ becomes comparable to the error for using step length $h$. However, I want a more rigorous argument.

I have done this for some simple examples of using difference methods. In particular, for approximating $f''(x)$ when the round-off error in each calculation is $\leq \epsilon$, I got

$$
\left| f''(x) - \frac{\bar{f}(x+2h) - 2\bar{f}(x+h) + \bar{f}(x)}{h^2} \right| \ \leq \frac{5}{3} h M + \frac{4\epsilon}{h^2} N,
$$

where $\bar{f}(x) = f(x) (1 + \epsilon)$, $M = \max_{\xi \in [\xi,\xi+2h]} | f'''(\xi) |$, and $N = \max_{\xi \in [\xi, \xi + 2h]} | f(\xi) |$. Using this, it is straight forward to find an estimate for the optimal $h$ by minimizing the error estimate. I would like to have an analogous expression for the estimate of the global error in Heun's method.

Comment: See my recent changes in my answer to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36619/floating-point-and-global-error. With that kind of compensated addition (essentially a quad precision adder) one can reduce the step size until the truncation error is equal to the (double) machine constant. Or more precisely, $|\tau(x)|h^p\sim ϵ|f(x)|$ if $\tau(x)h^{p+1}=y(x+h)-y(x)-h\Phi_f(x,y(x),h)$.